# How to use the json object 's field value(stored in the camunda context) in Camunda dmn input expression?

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

We have a json object named `application` that is stored in the camunda context. In the dmn decision model, I want to use the field value from the stored json object as input expression in the dmn to evaluate the rule.

Json model looks like this:

```
{
    "applicants": [
        {
            "age": 58,
            "city": "Vallda",
            "id": "1002406-1",
            "mainapplicant": true
        },
        {
            "age": 59,
            "city": "Vallda",
            "id": "1002406-2",
            "mainapplicant": false
        }
    ],
    "groupnbr": 120,
    "rate": 0.041
}
```

I have tried javascript expression like:

```
var mainApplicant = application.applicants[0];
mainApplicant.city;
```

But this is not working.

Please suggest how can I use the field *city* from the first element in the array of *applicants* In java e.g. I could use:

```
 application.applicants.get(0).city
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a FEEL expression in the DMN input to get the value.

```
${application.applicants.get(0).city}
```

[image: Example from Camunda Modeler DMN tool]